# Comentários com a licença em arquivos CSS ou JavaScript devem ou não ser mantidos?

Tags: javascript, css, cache, licença

Esta questão surge quando finalizo um mecanismo para realizar um *bundle* de ficheiros CSS e JS com consequente *cache*. Em muitos projetos todos nós utilizamos mecanismos que permitem reduzir o tamanho dos arquivos CSS e JS nos nossos projetos no entanto uma questão legal surge.

Sendo que para diminuir o tamanho destes arquivos o meu algoritmo elimina também todos os comentários, em bibliotecas como o jQuery entre outros nos comentários é colocado o "**License Disclaimer**" e ou o "**Copyright notice**".

Será uma violação de direitos eliminar este tipo de comentários tendo como principal objetivo a redução do tamanho de dados a viajar em *requests*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sempre lembrando que não sou advogado, muito menos especialista em licenciamento, por isso vou dizer sobre a prática de um desenvolvedor.

Essencialmente depende da licença. Se ela obriga você manter lá, então seria uma violação sim. Justamente por isso as boas ferramentas de minificação permitem fazer exceção a esses comentários.

Se você colocar em algum lugar do seu site, provavelmente poderá tirar desses arquivos sem infringir a licença. De novo, precisa ver a especificidade da licença, mas é uma solução que eu acho que se aplica quase universalmente. Desde que não seja algo escondido, que esteja desvinculado do uso dos arquivos, não tenha algum truque, acho que é até uma forma de deixar mais evidente o seu uso.

Algumas pessoas podem interpretar que bastaria estar junto no servidor e não precisa ser entregue ao navegador. Eu não iria por este caminho se quiser estar certo de que não está desrespeitando a exigência da licença. Mas se quiser insistir nisto, sugiro procurar um advogado especialista.

Não há consenso sobre isto mas vejo na minha humilde observação que a maioria acha que precisa manter a licença no arquivo minificado. Se não o fizer, o risco é seu.

Não gosta assim? Troque de biblioteca ou não use uma.

Ferramentas recomendadas para preservar a licença (leia a documentação para ver como obter o resultado desejado):

- [YUI Compressor](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208220014/https://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README)
- [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: a minha questão não é sobre se gosto ou não! penso que a resposta terá de situar dentro do que escreveu, ou seja, dentro do escopo de cada licença mas não tenho certezas. Quanto ao risco claro que é de quem o faz. Tratando-se de um mecanismo utilizado enquanto profissional para clientes estas questões tem de ser levadas a sério.

Comment: Sim, claro, mas você pode gostar ou não de ter que deixar a licença. Te dei a única alternativa neste caso. Na verdade se a licença permitir a compra do direito de tirá-la, também pode fazer isto, mas quase nada neste tipo de biblioteca é *dual licensing*. Se pode conviver com isto, ótimo, se não pode, escolha uma biblioteca que não exija isto.

Comment: Compreendi... o problema é que se trata de um mecanismo automático pelo não consigo saber que comentário contem ou não a licença. Estou a pensar manter os comentário de todos os "min.css" e de todos os outros o algoritmo retira...não é 100% mas penso que faz o trabalho.

Comment: Editei, vê se ajuda.

Comment: Grande comentário e grande ajuda a tua! Por isso é utilizado o comentário "\*!" ao invés do "\*".... agradeço-te imenso! esta pergunta e resposta devia de ser documentação! sem duvida!